# WebStorm Typescript "unresolved function or method"

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, ionic2

I'm trying to build deserializable models for an Ionic app. However, I'm facing some strange issue with WebStorm. All my models implement a `Deserializable` interface, which just contains

```
export interface Serializable<T> {
    deserialize(input: Object): T;
}
```

Now I have multiple models like this

```
import {Serializable} from './serializable'

export class Tag implements Serializable<Tag> {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    deserialize(input) {
        this.id = input.id;
        this.name = input.name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Basically, this works well for most objects. But for some objects WebStorm shows strange behaviour. Let me show an example. Please see the comments which describe my issue:

```
import {Serializable} from './serializable'
import {User} from './user'
import {Tag} from './tag'

export class Comment implements Serializable<Comment> {
    id: number;
    time: Date;
    text: string;
    author: User;

    deserialize(input) : Comment {
        this.id = input.id;
        this.time = new Date(input.time);
        this.text = input.text;

        // works well
        let test = new Tag().deserialize(input.test);
        // shows "unresolved function or method deserialize()" ??
        this.author = new User().deserialize(input.author); 
        // works well?
        let authorsTest = input.authorsTest.map(function(authorTest){return new User().deserialize(authorTest);});

        function wtf() {
            // works well ???
            this.author = new User().deserialize(input.author); 
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

The objects look quite exactly the same, just other members in them.
I have some objects which work, others which work not. The ones which work not, work as soon as they are wrapped in a method?

Also, when I <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> the `User` class name, it jumps to the correct class. When hovering it, it also shows that `User` is implementing `Deserializable` interface, so shouldn't it know the function?

EDIT: here is the user class:

```
import {Serializable} from './serializable'
import {Location} from './location'

export class User implements Serializable<User> {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: Location;
    favorited: boolean;
    description: string;
    images: string[];

    deserialize(input) : User {
        this.id = input.id;
        this.name = input.name;
        this.age = input.age;
        this.favorited = input.favorited;
        this.description = input.description;
        this.images = input.images;

        this.location = new Location().deserialize(input.location);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the definition of your `User` class? Also, check to see if your project contains any other things named "User" - I've noticed that WebStorm sometimes gets confused when there are name collisions at the project level even if there aren't any name collisions in any given file. Also, just to clarify - `tsc` still transpiles your files correctly, right? It's just WebStorm specifically giving you problems?

Comment: Added the user class. There is no other user class in the project, I'm just setting up a new project which very view classes yet. tsc on comment.ts works well.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23352